# Understanding clear about Diagnostics in Durable Functions

Tags: azure-functions-runtime, azure-durable-functions

I'am working with Durable functions having 3 activities that executes one by one.All 3 activity executed one by one with any delayed, but since few days activities are not running at all and got stopped from executing.I see no exceptions and logs except below one,

```
    [FunctionName("StartProcess")]
    public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
    //number of activities
     // RandomNumberGeneration
     // RandomNumberValidation
    //  DatabaseInsertion
    }
```

My StartProcess OrchestrationTrigger is executing always but not able to invoke  RandomNumberGeneration() Activity trigger.So I got below log when StartProcess() OrchestrationTrigger is executing and want to know more about it

```
0ee5eaa5ddb240d28df0f1077a563cc6: Function 'StartProcess (Orchestrator)', version '' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (42 bytes). State: Started. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: schedulars. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
Function started (Id=b8abdfcc-1794-4bea-b5b7-5a35bffacb4b)
0ee5eaa5ddb240d28df0f1077a563cc6: Function 'DatabaseInsertion (Activity)', version '' scheduled. Reason: StartProcess. IsReplay: False. State: Scheduled. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: schedulars. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
Function completed (Success, Id=b8abdfcc-1794-4bea-b5b7-5a35bffacb4b, Duration=18ms)
```

Below is log when StartProcess execute always and also invokes other activities.

```
Function started (Id=4e61d349-b6e5-4c04-9d85-8d490f2a4a4e)
    9573f926bf884bb0a519e5cd1434621c: Function 'StartProcess (Orchestrator)', version '' started. IsReplay: True. Input: (42 bytes). State: Started. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: schedulars. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
    9573f926bf884bb0a519e5cd1434621c: Function 'StartProcess (Orchestrator)', version '' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: True. Output: (null). State: Completed. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: schedulars. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
    Function completed (Success, Id=4e61d349-b6e5-4c04-9d85-8d490f2a4a4e, Duration=3270ms)
```

Gone through below Diagnostics in Durable Functions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-diagnostics

But not able to get it clearly

> Does StartProcess() is unable to start another activity because DataBaseInsertion() ActivityTrigger is already in scheduled state and waiting for completion of it?

please help in understanding What is issue and Why it is not running?

Comment: A couple questions: 1) What region is your function app running in? 2) if possible, would you mind sharing your code? What I want to know is which statements you're awaiting on in your code, as that's the point at which a Durable Functions orchestrator pauses and awaits completion of scheduled async work.

Comment: Addendum: It looks like you're running on a very old version of the extension; later releases improved diagnostics. Could you upgrade to the latest release and try to reproduce your issue?